# Display custom column with custom user meta on WooCommerce order admin list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

In a bit of a quandary here. I've been trying for a couple of days now to get my data, that I collected from a custom field in WooCommerce registration form to insert into user meta in database. The code for the form is:

```php
//Addition of morello Account Number to reg page
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'add_register_form_field' );
 
function add_register_form_field(){
 
    woocommerce_form_field(
        'morello_account_number',
        array(
            'type'        => 'text',
            'required'    => true, // required field?
            'label'       => 'morello Account Number:'
        ),
        ( isset($_POST['morello_account_number']) ? $_POST['morello_account_number'] : '' )
    );
 
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'save_register_fields' );
 
function save_register_fields( $customer_id ){
 
    if ( isset( $_POST['morello_account_number'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'morello_account_number', wc_clean( $_POST['morello_account_number'] ) );
    }
 
}
```

---

Now I want to grab the data from the table and display it on the Order page of WooCommerce in a separate column, so I can then see the morello number without having to search customer details manually.

Here's my code so far for this:

```php
/**
 * Add columns
 */
function morello_account_number_column( $columns ) {
    $columns['morello_account_number'] = "morello Account Number";
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'morello_account_number_column', 10, 1 );

/**
 * Populate columns
 */
function morello_placeholder( $column, $post_id ) {
    if( $column == 'morello_account_number' ) {
        // https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/
        $a_a_n = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'morello_account_number', true );

        // Value is found
        if ( !empty($a_a_n) ) {
            echo $a_a_n;    
        } else {
            echo 'something else';
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'morello_placeholder', 10, 2 );
```

---

This works as intended, but keeps displaying the "something else" quote - the code creates the column in the correct place, but won't populate it with the morello_account_number.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some small mistakes in your code.

---

> **NOTE:** Be aware that if you add a new field to the registration form, it is best to have this field returned in several places, so that the user can adjust it afterwards.
>
> See: https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-select-field-account-register-form/
>
> Part 3: **Display** Field **@ User Profile** (admin) and **My Account Edit** page (front end)

---

So you get

```
/**
 * Add morello account number to reg page
 */
function add_register_form_field() {
    ?>
    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide"> 
        <label for="reg_morello_account_number"><?php _e( 'Morello Account Number', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label> 
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="morello_account_number" id="reg_morello_account_number" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['morello_account_number'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['morello_account_number'] ); ?>" /> 
    </p> 
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'add_register_form_field' );

/**
 * Save morello account number
 */
function save_register_fields( $customer_id, $new_customer_data, $password_generated ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['morello_account_number'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'morello_account_number', wc_clean( $_POST['morello_account_number'] ) );
    }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'save_register_fields', 10 , 3 );

/**
 * Add columns
 */
function morello_account_number_column( $columns ) {
    $columns['morello_account_number'] = "morello Account Number";
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'morello_account_number_column', 10, 1 );

/**
 * Populate columns
 */
function morello_placeholder( $column, $post_id ) {
    // Get order
    $order = wc_get_order( $post_id );

    // Get user id
    $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
    
    if( $column == 'morello_account_number' ) {
        $a_a_n = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'morello_account_number', true );

        // Value is found
        if ( !empty($a_a_n) ) {
            echo $a_a_n;    
        } else {
            echo 'something else';
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'morello_placeholder', 10, 2 );
```