# How to add a custom textfield inside a custom column on the order admin page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I try to **add a new column** in order list admin page which **contains a custom text field**. To **add a new note to the selected order**.

```php
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'webtoffee_alter_order_columns');
function webtoffee_alter_order_columns($columns) {

    $new_columns = ( is_array($columns) ) ? $columns : array();

    unset($new_columns['order_number']);

    $res_array = array_slice($new_columns, 0, 1, true) + array("custom_order_number" => "Order Number") +  array_slice($new_columns, 1, count($new_columns)-1, true);

    return $res_array;
}

add_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'webtoffee_alter_order_number_columns', 10, 2);
function webtoffee_alter_order_number_columns($column) {
    global $post, $woocommerce, $the_order;

    if ($column === 'order_number') {

    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61155291/11987538, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61154118/show-order-notes-with-author-and-date-in-woocommerce-admin-order-list/61154817#61154817, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60628547/display-custom-column-with-custom-user-meta-in-woocommerce-orders-page/60628858#60628858... 
first take a look at the following examples and try to adjust your code accordingly, if you can't figure it out, you can still adjust your question. Regards

Comment: Thank you! But i need to add text field in the order table admin and not in the order user.

Comment: the idea is these examples allows me to display the notes created before in a column for each order row, but i want to add a column which each cell contains an input area that allows me to add new note to the order.

Comment: Okay, now I understand your question. 
My apologies for the misunderstanding

Comment: Adding a text field and a button to save is not that difficult in itself. You could write the value to the database with `update_post_meta` and then read it with `get_post_meta`. But i believe there should be a more efficient way, and to find it i would start from the order actions buttons and how they work, 
a hook that can certainly help you with this during the search is `woocommerce_admin_order_actions`. Good luck

Comment: Thank you!  When i add a text field in one of the columns and start writing in it, it forwards me to the edit order page. So, i think the most efficient way is to place it inside the edit order page and not in the orders list.

Comment: If you choose for that solution, the following tutorial can definitely help you https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/customize-order-details.html

Comment: Yeah! I learnt from it and everything is perfect. Thank You!